# How to trigger a Jenkins pipeline from multiple repositories

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am relatively new to Jenkins and I am working on a large project that pulls from multiple repos to build. I wrote a declarative pipeline with shell commands that pull from the required repos and build the project and everything is working but I want to connect this pipeline to all these repos so every time there is a new commit or a pull request, a Jenkins job is triggered and then I return the build result to tag the git commit. I know how to do this for one repo, but I don't know how to do it for multiple repos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of our network infrastructure I couldn't use webhook to trigger jenkins but the solution that I am using now is I created a runner for each repo and I wrote a curl command to trigger jenkins with so each time that there is a new commit to each of those repos the runner starts a new job, executes that curl command and triggers my jenkins job.

This is the curl command that I am using in case someone needed it:

```
curl -i -X POST --user [JENKINS_USERNAME]:[JENKINS_PASSWORD] 'http://[JENKINS_IP]:[JENKINS_PORT]/job/[JENKINS_JOB_NAME]/build?token=[TOKEN_GENERATED_INSIDE_JENKINS]&cause=[ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_PRINT]'
```

Comment: Could you please add these crucial details: where do we put that curl command? How can Jenkins credentials and webhook token be stored securely?

Comment: Those questions are beyond the scope of this question and their answers are heavily dependent on your infrastructure. We use GitLab, in GitLab you can write a runner that will get executed under certain conditions (push, merge, etc) and that is where I wrote the curl command. Again in the Gitlab groups/settings/CI/CD you can define variables that is only visible to the repos and people who have access to that group (including the runner) and that is where I store the credentials.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple repositories which should trigger Jenkins builds, the respective repositories need to have Jenkinsfiles in place.

The key is that every repository should call a JenkinsSharedLibrary, which gives you the ability to maintain your Jenkins builds in one central source, instead of having multiple "hardcoded" `Jenkinsfile`s per repository.

This article describes the use case of a shared library and how to use Jenkins across multiple git repos:
https://bjurr.se/managing-1000-repos-in-jenkins-with-a-breeze/

Comment: Thank you for the link. At the moment I have other things to work on and we are just running the pipeline manually but I also found this which uses a plugin (Multiple SCMs: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/04/jenkins-how-to-build-a-project-from-multiple-git-repositories.html) and it seems very promising and also simple to set up